# Copy multiple rows from one excel file to another using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large excel file (Around 10 MB) that is written out as a very long list of tables. I want to create a macro on a separate file that searches through the first file for a certain value and then returns the appropriate table. So far i have gotten the search functionality to work and i can return a single cell using offset, but when i go to return multiple records i receive a couple of different errors.

The section of the code i am currently trying to use to copy the cells is:

```
d = c + 7
For Counter = c To d
    objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname").Range(Cells(Counter, "A"), Cells(Counter, "M")).Value = Range("M3:Y10").Value
Next
```

In this case it should take each row and copy it to the section specified ( c is the cell currently being checked and d is the row number of the bottom of each seperate table) but instead i get the following error:

> Run-time error '1004'
>   Application-defined or object-defined error

I am fairly new at using VBA so i'm not sure if the error is very simple and i'm just not seeing it properly.

Comment: You need to show more code in the question

Comment: instead of looping a range try `Range.Find method`

Comment: @Warcupine I added the references and it doesn't error now but it seems to just delete the table itself instead of copying it to the other page. Thats something else that i can trouble shoot but still its progress so thank you very much

Comment: Based on your snippet, your loop doesn't appear to be searching for anything, just copying a static range to the new rows. If ```Range("M3:Y10").value``` is blank then it will wipe out whatever was in the looped ranges. The right side of the ```=``` shouldn't be deleted though, if that is the tables.

Comment: @Warcupine The code i posted is within another function that handles all the searching. The mistake i made was the values on either side of the equals sign, its all sorted now. Thank you a million times over for your help :). If you would like post an answer and i can tick it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cells(Counter, "A")`, `Cells(Counter, "M")`, and `Range("M3:Y10")` have no Workbook or Worksheet, so it is defaulting to the active one.

```
d = c + 7
For Counter = c To d
    with objWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname")
       'Not sure what the other workbook and sheet are called
       OtherWorkbook.Sheets("SheetnameHere").Range("M3:Y10").Value = .Range(.Cells(Counter, "A"), .Cells(Counter, "M")).Value 
    end with
Next
```